# How to prevent Bootstrap 4 alert from displaying on page load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, alert

I'm writing an application in MVC and I'm passing a success message to an auto-dismissing alert when the user adds an object to their order. However, I've set the alert to initially hide, it still displays on page load.

The alert still displays on page load, for the time stated in the JS snippet.

```
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["UpdResult"])))
    {
        <div id="DivMsg" class="alert alert-success agenda-update">
            @if(Convert.ToString(Session["UpdResult"]).Contains("Err"))
            {
            <div class="alert alert-danger agenda-update text-strong text-center" role="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                Sorry, something went wrong. Please
                <a href="#" target="_blank">contact us</a>
                to help with your sessions.
            </div>

            }
            else
            {
            <div class="alert alert-success agenda-update text-strong text-center" role="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                @Convert.ToString(Session["UpdResult"])
            </div>                                                
            }
        </div>

    }
    <!-- End Success & Error Messaging -->
```

**Javascript to hide alert initially**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $(".alert").hide();
            $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 4000);
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Why not `window.onload`?

Comment: Where does this js code exist? is it before the alert render or after?

Comment: It's in the view (not the layout (header/footer)) after the alert, base of the view code.

Comment: Unsure what you're asking - you _did_ set it to hide after some time, so....? As previously commented, why even do `timeout` instead of `onload` or jQuery `ready`

Comment: When the page loads, it appears and then hides. I don't want it to appear on pageload. It's designed only to display on a button click.